# GET Request is not working when I define Accept octet-stream output format

Tags: get, postman, response, octet-stream

I'm trying to execute a GET Request in Postman to a specific endpoint to retrieve an octet-stream that represents an Employee Picture.

It works using POST Request type, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: POST output - working correctly]

I know that the same service can be provided by using a GET request. I've tried this, and initially, it works when I don't add the Accept application/octet-stream in the Header of the GET Request:

[image: GET output - working correctly]

But, as you can see, it did not give me the binary output (jpg image). It just retrieves the file name.

If I add the Accept octet-stream (which I'm using in the POST request shown above), I get the following error in Postman output:

[image: GET output - error message]

Can I assume the service does not support accepting octet-stream in the GET Request? Or am I missing something in the GET Request in order to have the expected binary output as I have in the POST Request output?